# OSX Sierra constantly logging to console

Tags: macos

I've noticed in the console app on OSX Sierra that it bursts about 100 messages per second minimum.

All to do with opendirectoryd, deleted, securityd, identityservicesd, keychain errors

Some of the logs

```
default 20:53:40.570741 +0000   amfid   CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
default 20:53:40.570772 +0000   amfid   MacOS error: -67050
default 20:53:40.774748 +0000   securityd   looking for a common at /private/var/db/crls/crlcache2.db
default 20:53:40.778097 +0000   launchservicesd CSSM Exception: -2147411889 CSSMERR_CL_UNKNOWN_TAG
default 20:53:40.805489 +0000   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
default 20:53:40.887464 +0000   opendirectoryd  Client: <private>, UID: 501, EUID: 501, GID: 20, EGID: 20
default 20:53:43.122701 +0000   opendirectoryd  <private> failed with error '<private>' (2)
default 20:53:51.248548 +0000   securityd   0x7fff5aa948d0 dead connection 85559
```

I have found some posts online that its a keychain issue with Sierra, but does anyone here have some more info on this issue.

e.g. [Excessive Console logging on macOS Sierra](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68036)

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly by design and not at all abnormal to have tens of thousands of messages per hour now that Apple has transitioned from logging to text files in /private/var/log to using database and Apple's unified logging SDK/API going forward on all OS (macOS, iOS, watchOS, tvOS).

I too miss the days of tailing a log file from the command line and being able to see what's happening (or keeping console app open) and have started the process of setting up saved searches so I can see the log information I care about in the console app. However, over 8 days uptime, logging similar volume of messages - the daemons responsible for logging have accumulated under 2 minutes of total CPU time. In practice, it's just not a measurable load on the system to be this chatty. Unless you have a specific issue with keychain or open directory, I'd just filter those results from your view in console (or filter for just the messages you need to see).

Once I was convinced there wasn't a performance issue (no leaks, RAM stable, CPU usage and filesystem usage extremely reasonable and efficient), here are links that helped me decide to stop *(and perhaps rationalize)* worrying about chatty logs and just start filtering what I needed:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66984
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/
- https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html

ASL is really a different beast entirely from `syslog` even though they ultimately do the same thing and we need to consume the output of both from time to time.